# IndicatorAppletFactory::IndicatorApplet Warning

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel

When I boot, I often encounter this warning. How can I get rid of this?

> The panel encountered a problem while loading
>   "IndicatorAppletFactory::IndicatorApplet".
>   Do you want to delete the applet from
>   your configuration?

I use ubuntu 11.04.

In `$HOME/.xsession-errors`, the following part seems to be relevant.

```
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

(nautilus:1490): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (gnome-panel:1493): WARNING **: Failed to load applet IndicatorAppletFactory::IndicatorApplet:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.panel.applet.AppletFactory' on object at path /org/gnome/panel/applet/IndicatorAppletFactory
```

Comment: Which indicator applet does the system want to remove from your configuration?

Comment: @Kory It doesn't say in particular. But all I have is System Monitor, Indicator Applet, and a few launchers.

Comment: Has this error been noticed since you began using Ubuntu 11.04, or have you added some indicator applets recently?

Comment: It is since I began using Ubuntu 11.04. It seems to be a common problem, as I see other people reporting the same thing, but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: If you were to view the contents of `$HOME/.xsession-errors`, is there any indication of what might have gone awry?

Comment: @Kory I added part of the file.

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging.  I seem to recall having read somewhere where the `sleep` command was used.  However, I have not been successful in find the post.  I will keep looking and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your home folder

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

then your home folder will display hidden files

check whether any of the folders is locked

right click on the folder then click "properties". In that Click "permissions".

In owner, change folder access to "create and delete files."

And then click "Apply Permissions to Enclosed files"

If you cannot see any locked folders then select all folders and do the above